# Laravel Sail / Docker is too slow on Mac: optimization possible?

Tags: laravel, performance, docker, local, laravel-sail

Just installed Laravel Sail in an existing project. I really love the easy setup, but it seems way too slow for development. I'm running the latests Docker (20.10) on a Macbook Pro 2019. I gave Docker 6 cores and 8GB of RAM in the resource-settings.
The response times I'm getting are 700-800ms, sometimes even higher, for simple API calls. Coming from Laravel Valet this feels like a huge step back.

Comment: In fact, Docker is slow for all mac users I know. You could try [DockerSync](http://docker-sync.io/).